# Android full image with recyclerview, cardview and volley from php mysql

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-volley

The code below downloads images from a server and displays them in a recyclerview using php mysql and volley library as seen in the image. As of now when one clicks the image it only toasts the image name. I want a user to be able to view the full image on click. Sorry to post all the code but its a desperate situation.

RECYCLERVIEW CODE

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

CARDVIEW CODE

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/cardview1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardElevation="5dp"
    card_view:contentPadding="5dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
    card_view:cardMaxElevation="5dp"
    >


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ECEFF1">

        <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
            android:id="@+id/VolleyImageView"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ImageNameTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/VolleyImageView"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/VolleyImageView"
            android:text="JSon Image Name"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="15dp" />


    </RelativeLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

MAIN ACTIVITY

```
package com.ny.fetchallimages;

import android.os.Bundle;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import java.util.List;

import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    List<DataAdapter> ListOfdataAdapter;

    RecyclerView recyclerView;

    String HTTP_JSON_URL = "http://*************.php";

    String Image_URL_JSON = "image_data";

    String Image_Name_JSON = "image_tag";

    JsonArrayRequest RequestOfJSonArray ;

    RequestQueue requestQueue ;

    View view ;

    int RecyclerViewItemPosition ;

    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManagerOfrecyclerView;

    RecyclerView.Adapter recyclerViewadapter;

    ArrayList<String> ImageTitleNameArrayListForClick;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ImageTitleNameArrayListForClick = new ArrayList<>();

        ListOfdataAdapter = new ArrayList<>();

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview1);

        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        layoutManagerOfrecyclerView = new LinearLayoutManager(this);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManagerOfrecyclerView);

        JSON_HTTP_CALL();

        // Implementing Click Listener on RecyclerView.
        recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener() {

            GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(MainActivity.this, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {

                @Override public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent motionEvent) {

                    return true;
                }

            });
            @Override
            public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView Recyclerview, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

                view = Recyclerview.findChildViewUnder(motionEvent.getX(), motionEvent.getY());

                if(view != null && gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent)) {

                    //Getting RecyclerView Clicked Item value.
                    RecyclerViewItemPosition = Recyclerview.getChildAdapterPosition(view);

                    // Showing RecyclerView Clicked Item value using Toast.
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ImageTitleNameArrayListForClick.get(RecyclerViewItemPosition), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView Recyclerview, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

            }
        });


    }

    public void JSON_HTTP_CALL(){

        RequestOfJSonArray = new JsonArrayRequest(HTTP_JSON_URL,

                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                        ParseJSonResponse(response);
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    }
                });

        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);

        requestQueue.add(RequestOfJSonArray);
    }

    public void ParseJSonResponse(JSONArray array){

        for(int i = 0; i<array.length(); i++) {

            DataAdapter GetDataAdapter2 = new DataAdapter();

            JSONObject json = null;
            try {

                json = array.getJSONObject(i);

                GetDataAdapter2.setImageTitle(json.getString(Image_Name_JSON));

                // Adding image title name in array to display on RecyclerView click event.
                ImageTitleNameArrayListForClick.add(json.getString(Image_Name_JSON));

                GetDataAdapter2.setImageUrl(json.getString(Image_URL_JSON));

            } catch (JSONException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            ListOfdataAdapter.add(GetDataAdapter2);
        }

        recyclerViewadapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(ListOfdataAdapter, this);

        recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewadapter);
    }
}
```

RECYCLERVIEWADAPTER

```
package com.ny.fetchallimages;

import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView;

import java.util.List;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    Context context;

    List<DataAdapter> dataAdapters;

    ImageLoader imageLoader;

    public RecyclerViewAdapter(List<DataAdapter> getDataAdapter, Context context){

        super();
        this.dataAdapters = getDataAdapter;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cardview, parent, false);

        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);

        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder Viewholder, int position) {

        DataAdapter dataAdapterOBJ =  dataAdapters.get(position);

        imageLoader = ImageAdapter.getInstance(context).getImageLoader();

        imageLoader.get(dataAdapterOBJ.getImageUrl(),
                ImageLoader.getImageListener(
                        Viewholder.VollyImageView,//Server Image
                        R.mipmap.ic_launcher,//Before loading server image the default showing image.
                        android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert //Error image if requested image dose not found on server.
                )
        );

        Viewholder.VollyImageView.setImageUrl(dataAdapterOBJ.getImageUrl(), imageLoader);

        Viewholder.ImageTitleTextView.setText(dataAdapterOBJ.getImageTitle());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        return dataAdapters.size();
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public TextView ImageTitleTextView;
        public NetworkImageView VollyImageView ;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {

            super(itemView);

            ImageTitleTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ImageNameTextView) ;

            VollyImageView = (NetworkImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.VolleyImageView) ;

        }
    }
}
```

IMAGEADAPTER

```
package com.ny.fetchallimages;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import android.content.Context;;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.DiskBasedCache;
import com.android.volley.Cache;
import androidx.collection.LruCache;

import com.android.volley.Network;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack;

public class ImageAdapter {

    public static ImageAdapter imageAdapter;

    public Network networkOBJ ;

    public RequestQueue requestQueue1;

    public ImageLoader Imageloader1;

    public Cache cache1 ;

    public static Context context1;

    LruCache<String, Bitmap> LRUCACHE = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(30);

    private ImageAdapter(Context context) {

        this.context1 = context;

        this.requestQueue1 = RequestQueueFunction();

        Imageloader1 = new ImageLoader(requestQueue1, new ImageLoader.ImageCache() {

            @Override
            public Bitmap getBitmap(String URL) {

                return LRUCACHE.get(URL);
            }

            @Override
            public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {

                LRUCACHE.put(url, bitmap);
            }
        });
    }

    public ImageLoader getImageLoader() {

        return Imageloader1;
    }

    public static ImageAdapter getInstance(Context SynchronizedContext) {

        if (imageAdapter == null) {

            imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(SynchronizedContext);
        }
        return imageAdapter;
    }

    public RequestQueue RequestQueueFunction() {

        if (requestQueue1 == null) {

            cache1 = new DiskBasedCache(context1.getCacheDir());

            networkOBJ = new BasicNetwork(new HurlStack());

            requestQueue1 = new RequestQueue(cache1, networkOBJ);

            requestQueue1.start();
        }
        return requestQueue1;
    }
}
```

DATAADAPTER

```
package com.ny.fetchallimages;

public class DataAdapter
{
    public String ImageURL;
    public String ImageTitle;

    public String getImageUrl() {

        return ImageURL;
    }

    public void setImageUrl(String imageServerUrl) {

        this.ImageURL = imageServerUrl;
    }

    public String getImageTitle() {

        return ImageTitle;
    }

    public void setImageTitle(String Imagetitlename) {

        this.ImageTitle = Imagetitlename;
    }

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it to show full images by fetching the url and parsing it to a new activity. Thanks for the positive responses

Answer (score 0):

just when the user clicked on an item do like me...

```
Intent i = new Intent(context,BigImageActivity);
intent.putExtra("image_url",iamge_url);
context.startActivity(i);
```

in big_image_layout.xml

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_big_image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />
```

in onCreate BigImageActivity:

```
String img_url = getIntent.getStringExtra("image_url");
```

and for showing image use Glide:

```
  Glide.with(context)
            .load(img_url)
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
            .dontAnimate()
            .into(iv_big_image);
```

and done!!!
I hope this useful for you.

Comment: Thank you @Arad Sheybak but in which class exactly will i implement this?. Is it possible to show how to load full using volley instead of glide?

Comment: glide is a library for showing images and volley is Http library, These two are irrelevant

Comment: Thank You sir. But I am still unable to implement this.

Comment: When you click on an item, the name of the image appears as a toast message, right? write the Intent to NewActivity instead of the Toast, it's simple

Comment: Thanks @Arad Sheybak. How to get the clicked image url ion the new activity?

Comment: YW, with putExtra you can send a value from an activity to another activity